# Add to linked list using function

Tags: c++, linked-list

I want to add item to a linked list (course object).

```
course* start = ....;       // course pointer as start of list
course* c = ....;           // another course object pointer to add to list
```

Then to add to the list, I use:

```
course* temp = start;       // copy start current value to a temp object
start = c;                  // set start value to newest object
c->next = temp;             // linked back to previous object
return start;               // return result
```

That works, but now I want to wrap that into a function named addToEnd():

```
addToEnd(start, c);
```

with

```
void addToEnd(course* start, course* c)
{
    // LIFO
    course* temp = start;       // copy start current value to a temp object
    start = c;                  // set start value to newest object
    c->next = temp;             // linked back to previous object
}
```

The change occurs only inside the function, and has no effect outside.  What have I done wrong?

And NO!  My question is different from the suggested 'LinkedList C++ implementation' question.

Comment: I strongly recommend making a linked list class that contains linked nodes which contain a `course`. The direction you are headed looks better suited to programming in C. Not that that's a bad thing, but not the best way to write C++.

Comment: I do agree that is more generic.  However, I am only to solve this problem first.

Comment: I'd even more strongly recommend using the standard library list and vector classes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LinkedList C++ implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140249/linkedlist-c-implementation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now this is going to sound silly, but you are passing the pointers by value.

Silly right? They're pointers. You don't get much more pass by reference than a pointer. Well, it's the item being pointed AT that's being passed by reference. The pointer itself... Not so much.

So what happens is `start` is an Automatic (also known as local) variable that contains an address. The address the caller passed into the function is copied into `start`. When you change `start` inside the function it is changing the copy and when the function ends, `start` is gone. The caller has no clue `start` was ever changed.

If you want to update a pointer inside a function, you have to pass the pointer itself by reference

```
void addToEnd(course*& start, course* c) // note the only change required is the 
                                          // addition of the &
{
    // LIFO
    course* temp = start;       // copy start current value to a temp object
    start = c;                  // set start value to newest object
    c->next = temp;             // linked back to previous object
}
```

so that the caller gets the updated value.

More reading: [What's the difference between passing by reference vs. passing by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value)

Answer (score 1):

**Note: I wrote this thinking C, not C++. The answer works, but isn't ideal. @user4581301's answer is better.**

The short answer is: Changes to "start" won't be visible outside the function, but changes to "*start" will be.

Likely you would want to pass a pointer to a pointer to the function.

So something like

```
addToEnd(&start, c);
```

and

```
void addToEnd(course** start, course* c)
{
    // LIFO
    course* temp = *start;       // copy start current value to a temp object
    *start = c;                  // set start value to newest object
    c->next = temp;             // linked back to previous object
}
```

Comment: Works, but this being C++ you should prefer to use a reference to the pointer rather than a pointer to the pointer.

Comment: You saved my butt, dawg!  I am a bit confused with pointer to pointer.

Comment: user4581301, thank you for your point.  You surely are very experienced with this.  Point taken.

Comment: Thanks. Pretty sloppy of me. I will leave the answer but add a warning.